# Destroy cluster windows server 2012 r2

Tags: sql-server, clustering, windows-server, high-availability

I want know how to delete a Windows Server Failover Cluster. My case is a bit special.

I encountered some problems while creating a failover cluster, and I stopped the cluster services then I did "evict nodes", then "destroy cluster".

Then the cluster disappears and now I can no longer recreate a cluster because it tells me that the servers are in a cluster. In this case how to delete a cluster which is not visible in server manager?

It's for SQL Server high availability.

Comment: Can you please add the error message you are getting, in the question

Comment: @Shanky when i try to create the cluster , i have this error message when i select the servers "The computer 'node01.corp.gh.mg' is joined to a cluster" .

Comment: T[his MSDN thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/d81881ec-9d76-4215-8529-1496456e45b1/error-the-computer-is-joined-to-cluster-when-creating-the-cluster?forum=winserverClustering) should help you. Basically you would have to remove things manually using PS

Comment: @Shanky thank you guy , it works but now the problem is that validating the cluster take too much time , it's blocked on "List Software Updates", i don't know what is the real problem

Comment: And if you somehow get this cleaned up, you intend to continue with building a failover cluster with these OS instances?  I would start over with clean installs, and preferably a later version of Windows Server.